# How to print an entire data frame in R on a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: r, dataframe

No matter what I do (e.g. just calling the dataframe `df` or `print(df)` or `df[1:nrow(df),]` I get vertical dots in the printout skipping rows:

[image]

There are similar questions on the site about RStudio, and suggestion `View()`. However, this function is not supported in Jupyter Notebook (specifically, I am using Google Colab).

I am interested in a call or function within R (or R package) to do this independent of the IDE or platform I may be using.

Comment: Try using Anaconda. Google Colab and Jupyter Notebook work differently for some functions.

Comment: Try changing the printing options ie `options(repr.matrix.max.rows=1000)`  for example and see what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the options you want are `repr.matrix.max.rows` and `repr.matrix.max.cols`.

Try to run this:

```
options(repr.matrix.max.rows=600, repr.matrix.max.cols=200)
```

The defaults are 60 and 20.

Link: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/470